# Best Way to find Identical Key-Value pairs in List of Dictionaries Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

If I have a list of dictionaries such as

```
[{'D': 'wet', 'W': 'sun'}, {'D': 'wet', 'W': 'rain'}, {'D': 'wet', 'W': 'sun'}]
```

What would be the best way to detect if there is a Key-Value pair that is identical between all dictionaries in the list. So in this case, "D" : "Wet" would be identical because it is the same across all the Key and Values of the list of dictionaries. However, the "W" will not be because it has more a >1 domain (sun and rain are both in the domain of the W key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also take advantage of the intersection property built into sets

```
dict(set.intersection(*(set(d.items()) for d in dicts)))
```

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know `set.intersection` took variable arguments. It's not even documented. Also nice addition of the `dict` at the end.

Comment: just glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.items()` to convert each dictionary into an iterable of `(key, value)` tuples, convert those iterables to sets, then collapse them all with intersection:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a & b,
       (set(d.items()) for d in
        [{'D': 'wet', 'W': 'sun'}, {'D': 'wet', 'W': 'rain'}, {'D': 'wet', 'W': 'sun'}]))
```

In Python 3 you will need `from functools import reduce`.